# How will spells resolve MTG

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So I have 1/2 creature, opponent uses shock to kill it, then I answer with my giant growth and opponent responds with another shock. Will my creature survive or die?
which spells will resolve first.
I cast giant growth on 1/1 creature and enemy responds with shock. Will my creature take 2 damage first because shock is on top of a stack or will giant growth give +3/+3 to that creature until shock hits it?

Comment: Its not duplicate i wasnt able to find answer on that post

Comment: @SharaShara out of curiosity are you playing in paper magic or online in Magic Arena?

Comment: paper  also i am a beginner

Comment: @SharaShara Could you explain why the linked to question/answer didn't answer your question?  From my perspective it does, but I'm not a beginner either....

Comment: english isnt my main language and i cant understand it very well so i want a simple answer will my creature die or survive

Comment: @SharaShara your question is covered in the linked duplicate answer, but if you would like a bit of explanation to your specific misunderstandings you can hop into [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49/board-and-card-games).

Comment: i cant "hop in " because i havnt enough reputation

Comment: @SharaShara you should still be able to read chat, even though you don't have the rep to answer

Comment: ok.. just tell me will my  1/1 creature die or survive if i cast giant growth and my enemy responds with shock if you cant answer just tell me and i'l search different forum

Comment: I spelled out the interaction for you in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49/board-and-card-games) have a look there. Comments here isn't a good spot for answering your question as they will be cleaned up and deleted shortly.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for being rude ( if i was rude idk :D )

Comment: @SharaShara No problem, welcome to the site. Once you get a bit more rep (20) you will be able to participate in chat as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your creature will die, if your opponent plays correctly.

Here's your opponent's correct line of play in detail.

Opponent plays Shock.  Shock is on the Stack.  Your opponent decided to do nothing else (also known as "passes priority") and you get a chance to respond.  You do, by casting Giant Growth.  You have nothing else to do, so you pass priority.  Your opponent gets a chance to respond before any spells resolve.

The stack is now:

- Giant Growth
- Shock

Your opponent casts Shock, and passes priority, and the stack looks like:

- Shock
- Giant Growth
- Shock

You pass priority (i.e. you have nothing else you can do.)  Spells resolve one at a time, the most recently cast spell resolving first.

Your opponent's Shock does two points of damage to your creature.  Your creature dies, before your Giant Growth resolves.